# Bizarre ActiveRecord issues - like generating invalid SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Recently we deployed a new version of our app, and since then we've been seeing some really weird issues with ActiveRecord. For example, here's a snippet of a query it generates hundreds of times per day, usually correctly:

```
`entries`.`style` AS t1_r25, `entries`.`pdf_visibility` AS       , `entries`.`web_visibility` AS t1_r27
```

That's not a typo, t1_r26 is missing there although there's a space where it should be. But only that one time. That's not hand-written SQL, either, that's ActiveRecord writing the query and deciding on all the placeholder variables. It has similarly botched other queries leaving things blank that shouldn't be blank (shouldn't even be possible), but only once in a while. Most of the time it's fine.

We're also seeing a lot of instances where it complains about things like table_alias or reflection being an undefined variable or method on false:FalseClass. That's true...but the thing that is a FalseClass should have been an ActiveRecord model. We have no clue how any of this is happening, or how we could possibly have written a bug in our Rails code that would do most of this (especially the invalid query above).

We're on Rails 4.1.16 (we upgraded from 4.1.8 when this started happening) with Ruby 2.2.0 in Passenger 5.0.26 (going to 5.0.30 next). These errors are extremely sporadic and none of them make any sense. Out of thousands of requests per day, only a small handful of them (less than 10 across 5 servers) result in one of these weird errors, and we can't purposely reproduce any of them.

My entire team is stumped. We've spent hours poring over code changes and can't see anything that might cause any of this. We don't even know what we could possibly have written that would cause ActiveRecord to sometimes write a bad query in a way that we shouldn't be able to affect. We have no idea how to begin troubleshooting this kind of thing. Does anyone out there have a hint that might point us in some useful direction?

Update: Here's a new one it threw this morning. Note that LibraryItem is one of our pretty straightforward ActiveRecord models:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `__callbacks' for #<LibraryItem:0x007f66cc5b82b0>
```

I...have no idea.

Comment: is the concern t1_r25? looks like a join to me - is there a test that's not working correctly?

Comment: No, it's this: "`entries`.`pdf_visibility` AS       ,"

It didn't give that variable a name. There's no failing test, these just pop up in production extremely infrequently.

Comment: Interesting... I know nothing about your hosting environment, but can you run memtest on your servers?

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the error in a smaller sample app?

Comment: @BradWerth - We run in AWS. This is happening across 5 different instances on different hardware.

@pascalbetz - We haven't even been able to reproduce it in the large app. One of these errors happened once in our test environment, but we haven't been able to recreate that.

Here's one it tossed at us this morning: NoMethodError: undefined method `__callbacks' for #<LibraryItem:0x007f66cc5b82b0>

LibraryItem is just a straightforward ActiveRecord model...how the heck does it not have __callbacks? Idunno.

Comment: Wow, that's rough... Are the servers overtaxed? It really sounds like a hardware issue... I know it's on AWS, but maybe it gets weird when it is out of resources. I wish I had some more insight to provide, this sounds like a dreadful problem.

Comment: Maybe you can run something like apachebench against the failing operation, locally, in an attempt to reproduce. It might be easy to try, and could probably tell you if it happens more frequently when resources are exhausted.

Comment: @BradWerth - Yeah, we've been trying to load up our test server with JMeter and just can't make it happen. It's really frustrating. We're upgrading Passenger on one of the production servers tonight, and barring any issues we'll upgrade the rest shortly thereafter. This is an approach I like to call "grasping at straws." :)

Comment: Did this start on 4.1.8, then you upgraded to 4.1.16 to try and resolve it? or did you upgrade to 4.1.16 and start seeing problems?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Is it Postgres? Do you use Postgres schemas or modify search_path by any chance? Also can you post stacktraces for those errors?

Comment: @JohnNaegle - Yes, it started after an app deployment on 4.1.8 (we'd been running 4.1.8 for about a year). We thought maybe we'd deployed something that tickled an ActiveRecord bug we'd never triggered before, so we tried an upgrade to 4.1.16 as a hail mary. It didn't do anything.

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak - We use MySQL. I'll try to post a stack trace or two in a pastebin or something and link it here.

Comment: Maybe Passenger could be [an issue](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1797) if you are getting a memory leak + a lot of requests? Interested to see if your "grasping at straws" [upgrade](https://blog.phusion.nl/2016/04/28/passenger-5-0-28/) changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop for those who tried to help and for anyone who stumbles into this: We cured it by upgrading MRI. We'd been running on 2.2.0 for around a year, which was why we didn't immediately suspect it, and also because this started with a particular deployment. I was tipped off when we saw a couple of errors about an inability to allocate memory, and when MRI exploded in a hail of shrapnel on one server (by which I mean it segfaulted) and took Passenger down with it.

From there I started looking at MRI changelogs and noticed a *ton* of memory and GC related bug fixes between 2.2.0 and 2.2.5. Last night we upgraded to 2.2.5 with a deployment, and (fingers crossed) we haven't seen a single one of these weird issues yet. (Previously we were seeing 12-20 per day or more, depending on traffic).

So, why did it start happening following a deployment for us? I don't know for sure, but I have a guess: I'm thinking the size in bytes of our application in memory finally hit some critical mass at which it started triggering one or more of the MRI bugs that were fixed between 2.2.0 and 2.2.5. Best I can come up with.

Huge thanks to those who stepped in to try to assist!